# slim exception not sure whats going wrong

Tags: php, slim

I'm using slim 4, and the URL im using is http://localhost/MyApi/public/hello/WeAreLearningPHP

Details

> Type: Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException
>   Code: 404
>   Message: Not found.
>   File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php
>   Line: 91
>
> Trace
>   0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(57): Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->performRouting(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
>
> 1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(132): Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->process(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(Slim\Routing\RouteRunner))
>
> 2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApi/vendor/selective/basepath/src/BasePathMiddleware.php(52): class@anonymous->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
>
> 3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(132): Selective\BasePath\BasePathMiddleware->process(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(class@anonymous))
>
> 4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/ErrorMiddleware.php(89): class@anonymous->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
>
> 5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(132): Slim\Middleware\ErrorMiddleware->process(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(class@anonymous))
>
> 6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(73): class@anonymous->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
>
> 7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(208): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
>
> 8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(192): Slim\App->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
>
> 9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApi/public/index.php(28): Slim\App->run()
>
> 10 {main}

----------------index.php-------------------

```
<?php

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Selective\BasePath\BasePathMiddleware;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

// Add Slim routing middleware
$app->addRoutingMiddleware();

// Set the base path to run the app in a subdirectory.
// This path is used in urlFor().
$app->add(new BasePathMiddleware($app));

$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);

// Define app routes
$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $response->getBody()->write('Hello, World!');
    return $response;
})->setName('root');

// Run app
$app->run();
```

Comment: You are defining a route of `/` but then you try to access the route `/MyApi/public/hello/WeAreLearningPHP`, that's where the 404 is coming in. Is your [web server configured correctly](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/start/web-servers.html)?

Comment: Please avoid unneccessary tagging - I don't think that this question is related to either Composer or REST

Comment: The public/ directory must not be part of the url path.
Try to open this first: `http://localhost/MyApi`
Did you also add the 2 required .htaccess files?